# Cannot start new MySQL process - Linux

Tags: mysql, linux, centos

I have created a new MySQL cluster by this:

```
mysqld --initialize-insecure --basedir=/var/lib --datadir=/var/lib/mysql2 --defaults-file=/etc/my2.cnf
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql2
chmod 777 /var/lib/mysql2
```

my config file looks like this:

```
datadir=/var/lib/mysql2
socket=/var/lib/mysql2/mysql2.sock

log-error=/var/log/mysqld2.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld2.pid
port=2222
```

whenever i run: `mysqld --defaults-file=/etc/my2.cnf -u root`
It creates the process + socket for a second and then aborted, the log I receive is this:

```
2021-01-04T15:09:15.069657Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.22) starting as process 16704
2021-01-04T15:09:15.091392Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-01-04T15:09:15.787218Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
2021-01-04T15:09:15.886765Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010735] [Server] Could not open the mysql.plugin table. Please perform the MySQL upgrade procedure.
2021-01-04T15:09:16.887822Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011292] [Server] Plugin mysqlx reported: 'Preparation of I/O interfaces failed, X Protocol won't be accessible'
2021-01-04T15:09:16.887985Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011300] [Server] Plugin mysqlx reported: 'Setup of bind-address: '*' port: 33060 failed, `bind()` failed with error: Address already in use (98). Do you already have another mysqld server running with Mysqlx ?'
2021-01-04T15:09:16.888098Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013597] [Server] Plugin mysqlx reported: 'Value '*' set to `Mysqlx_bind_address`, X Plugin can't bind to it. Skipping this value.'
2021-01-04T15:09:16.888217Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011300] [Server] Plugin mysqlx reported: 'Setup of socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' failed, another process with PID 7487 is using UNIX socket file'
2021-01-04T15:09:17.039111Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010015] [Repl] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
2021-01-04T15:09:17.225731Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010015] [Repl] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
2021-01-04T15:09:17.251232Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2021-01-04T15:09:17.251408Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2021-01-04T15:09:17.293753Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010441] [Server] Failed to open optimizer cost constant tables
2021-01-04T15:09:17.294070Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013129] [Server] A message intended for a client cannot be sent there as no client-session is attached. Therefore, we're sending the information to the error-log instead: MY-001146 - Table 'mysql.component' doesn't exist
2021-01-04T15:09:17.294248Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013129] [Server] A message intended for a client cannot be sent there as no client-session is attached. Therefore, we're sending the information to the error-log instead: MY-003543 - The mysql.component table is missing or has an incorrect definition.
2021-01-04T15:09:17.294774Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010326] [Server] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist
2021-01-04T15:09:17.294978Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010952] [Server] The privilege system failed to initialize correctly. For complete instructions on how to upgrade MySQL to a new version please see the 'Upgrading MySQL' section from the MySQL manual.
2021-01-04T15:09:17.295351Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2021-01-04T15:09:18.851807Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.22)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

If i try to start the process with the default conf file (the one created when I installed `mysql` via `yum`) the process works and also the socket. but for some reason it gets aborted for my new cluster.

Comment: **Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist.** Seems database was not initialized successfully.

Comment: try below steps once: `cd /var/lib/mysql2`. then `ls -l mysql/user*`

Comment: I get nothing when running it :(

Comment: Then DB is not initialized.

Comment: use `mysql_secure_installation` to initial database.